# Bootstrap Dropdown Custom Toggle Not Opening in Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have a custom dropdown toggle that will display a list of items. This works as it should on my static HTML site, however while converting to Wordpress, the toggle no longer works. This is what it should look like:

[image]

When the caret is clicked on the Wordpress site, the dropdown refuses to appear. Something is strange because I placed the default dropdown menu direct from the Bootstrap components page and the dropdown carent button did not show properly either.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="playlist-select">
        <div class="discovery-mode">
                DISCOVERY MODE
        </div>
        <div class="playlist-choice">
            <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle playlist-select-dropdown" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                    FRESH FINDS
                    <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu select-dropdown" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Did you add the css to the site? or link to it in your html?

Comment: Hi @mlegg yes, I've added `<link href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />` in my header.php already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to enqueue bootstrap to the footer of your site to get this to work properly:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','load_bootstrap');
function load_bootstrap() {
wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap', //path to bootstrap or cdn here, array(), '', true);
}
```

Main theme:
`wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri(). '/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js', array(), '', true);`

Child theme: `wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js', array(), '', true);`

The true part of that code loads the js in the footer so that it comes in and applies after the dom is ready.

Comment: hi, I have already added the bootstrap JS in my footer as: `<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>`

Comment: Try to add the code listed above by @Poldira in your functions.php than tell us if it works correctly please

Comment: Hi @SidBiffi attempted to add in the functions.php without any luck.
`add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','load_bootstrap');
function load_bootstrap() {
wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap', '/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js', array(), '', true);
}`

Comment: You have to include the theme directory.
Main theme:
wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri(). '/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js', array(), '', true);

Child theme:
wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js', array(), '', true);

Comment: I guess I'm just a little confused as to where to place scripts exactly. If it helps, I've noticed on my static site that my .playlist-choice becomes .playlist-choice.open and ariaexpanded = "true" on static site but these are not updated on the dynamic wordpress site when the button is pressed. Do you still believe this has to do with bootstrap? I am using a bootstrap menu that works as it should already @Poldira

Comment: @JordanLewallen Place my code into your functions file. Remove bootstrap js from the footer.php and header.php. There may need to be extra work done on the header for this to work completely, but lets get bootstrap added properly first.

Comment: @Poldira ah that fixed it for some reason! Guess I didnt throw it in properly into my functions.php last attempt. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Might be Possible you need to check z-index. I think so overflow:hidden or no proper position is causing an issue to it.

Comment: I adjusted Zindex on the ul class with no luck :(